# Proof Check (Hardy Maximal Function )

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove that 
if $Mf(x) \in L^1(R^n)$ then f = 0.
 Where Mf(x) is the hardy littlewood maximal function defined in the following way

$Mf(x) = sup_{0<r<\infty} 1/(\lambda(B(x,r))* \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy$

My proof is as follows -

Let $|x|>a $, for any arbitrary a

$Mf(x)\geq 1/(\lambda(B(x,2|x|))\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy$

$Mf(x) \geq 1/(\pi*(2x)^n)\int_{B(x,a)} |f(y)|dy$

Now 
$\int Mf(x)dx \geq \int(1/(\pi*(2x)^n)\int_{B(x,a)} |f(y)|dy)$

Let $\int_{B(x,a)} |f(y)|dy)= constant $

$\int Mf(x)dx \geq \int(1/(\pi*(2x)^n)*C)$

and we know that $1/(x^n)$ isn't integrable for $n\geq 1 $. Hence proved .

My main doubt in this proof is that can I assume that $\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy)= constant $ .

Please let me know if I am missing something at any other step too .